Why is one of the Intel 8042 keyboard controller outputs inverted?
The IBM PC/AT includes an Intel 8042 microcontroller mask-programmed to act as a keyboard controller. From the processor, it is accessible through two ports at addresses 60h and 64h, and it communicates with the keyboard over a synchronous serial connection consisting of one clock and one data line. These are connected to 5V through a pull-up resistor and can be pulled low by both ends (the AT keyboard protocol is bidirectional).
For reading from the keyboard, the controller connects the two lines to the inputs T0 and T1, which can be directly referenced by conditional branch instructions in 8042 assembly. For output, it uses the most significant bits of port 2 (called P27 and P26). The inputs can be directly routed to the keyboard connector, but the port pins are not open-collector outputs, so some external wiring is required for them.
The output for the data line (P27) is high when the line should be left high, and low when it should be pulled low. But the output for the clock line (P26) is low when the line should be released, and high when it should be pulled. See here for a very detailed description of the 8042's operation. This is apparently a rather obscure fact, in most descriptions of the PC's keyboard interface it is not mentioned at all. But it is true, and it applies not only to Intel's chips – I have a NEC D80C42C, which seems to have been a relatively popular chip in the late 80s, early 90s, and it behaves in the same way. The Winbond W83C42 keyboard controller does the same thing. So – what could be the reason for inverting the clock output?

An educated guess may be: because certain methods of creating an open-collector/open-drain interface would invert the signal, and one might prefer to fix this in software rather than add another inversion step. OK, but then the question becomes: why was the data signal not inverted?

No source for that idea, so just a comment: I am with your guess. The AT design uses the 7406 driver which inverts the signals, so "inverted" is preferred - but only if it does not complicate the keyboard controller firmware. CLK is just convention, inverting it makes no extra trouble. On the other hand, data to be sent needs to be actively inverted, as the controller also needs to deal with the internal non-inverted data.

@MichaelKarcher Which design uses 7406? I am looking at AT motherboard schematics and it used a 74ALS00 as an inverter and 7407 as non-inverting open-collector buffer.

@Justme You are correct. Many later (clone) designs use a 7406. As the original AT does not, the theory of "clock is inverted to use a 7406" is obviously wrong. Thanks for the input. Later PS/2-type keyboard controllers have all output inverted and are often used with 4 out of 6 gates of a 7406. You also find the 7406 in KBC datasheets.

The 8042 I/O ports are basically open-collector I/O pins. They have no control of I/O direction so they are always bi-directional. Intel used the term quasi-bidirectional, and that term is even today present in some chips with similar I/O structures.
The MCU can always read the actual state of the pin when used as an input, but when used as an output, the MCU can either pull the pin low or simply not pull the pin low.
The I/O pins have always present weak internal pull-up resistors to 5V supply voltage, so when the MCU does not pull the pin low, it will float idle at logic high level, unless some other device pulls the pin low (if used as an input or bi-directional pin).
When the 8042 is first powered up and  reset, the I/O pins state during the startup and reset is high, before the software runs and starts to initialize and control the I/O pins as needed.
Since the MCU output idles high before firmware runs, the inverter on clock output means that the keyboard bus clock wire is pulled low, until the firmware initializes itself and runs properly, when it pulls the MCU output pin low, which lets the keyboard bus clock to the idle high level.
This way, the keyboard controller side makes sure to pull the clock low and prevents (inhibits) the keyboard from transmitting anything until the keyboard controller is ready for reception of the first transmission from the keyboard. At this point the keyboard may already have completed the Basic Assurance Test and is ready to signal it by sending the byte 0xAA if it was successful or 0xFC if it failed.
Apart from this minor detail which allows the hardware to keep the keyboard inhibited until the keyboard controller is ready and releases the line, there should very few other reasons to invert the clock signal in hardware. AFAIK it would have been possible for the controller to request reset of the keyboard which would make it start over with the BAT, but just by having a small hardware detail may make the startup and synchronization process that the software needs to do much simpler.
This is also the reason why data signal is not inverted - it will idle high, as pulling it low would signal to the keyboard that the PC wants to transmit data to it, e.g. a command to update the Num/Caps/Scroll Lock LED state.

This is indeed a perfectly plausible explanation. And I was indeed wrong to think these were push-pull outputs.
